# Where is my redirect coming from?

Tags: iis-7.5, redirect

I have received an old system, and trying to figure where my redirect is coming from

The main inetpub/wwwroot page is as follows:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>OptiTex maintenance page</TITLE>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://ws.optitex.com/OptiTexWebApplication/Pages/Homepage.aspx">
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="FFFFFF">
<CENTER><IMG SRC="LogoNew.gif" ALIGN="BOTTOM"> </CENTER>
<HR>
<a href="http://www.optitex.com">www.optitex.com</a><br><br>

You are being redirected. <br>

<HR>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I am trying to change that, but even if I delete the Default.htm page from the folder, I still get the same behaviour when browsing to the page
My Default Document list for the Default Web site is:

[image]

Nothing seems to effect the redirect page.

Here is my wwwroot folder (nothing there)

[image]

Where should I look further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason I can't post this as a comment to your question so here goes an answer.

Could be:

- browser caches redirect parameters;
- one of the other Default Document files present in the root folder (maybe hidden);
- server config.

If you're using Firefox - try to debug this with Firebug or HttpFox to see what happens and what headers are received. If any other browser - there should be some built-in or 3rd-party tools available.

Comment: Thanks, I also used this site http://www.seoimage.com/seo-tools/check-redirect-and-server-header.html . It must have been a browser cache.